# What's the next letter?

Tags: letter-sequence, sequence

Can you determine which letter comes next?

[image]

In text

`U R R R A U ?`

**HINT 1**

> It follows the rule which is above your head

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next letter is

> U

because

> the sequence takes the middle letter of each month, first of the middle letters in case the number of letters is even. janUary, febRuary, maRch, apRil, mAy, jUne, jUly

Comment: Yes it's correct!

Comment: I didn't understand the hint

Comment: @Ak19 Could you explain the hint?

Comment: I meant the ceil (ceiling) function. For e.g. January has 7 letters, ceil(7/2) = ceil(3.5) = 4, i.e, the 4th letter 'U' and so on